# going from apex 5.0 to 5.1.2. will a 5.0 app run on 5.1.2 without being "touched" in a developer instance?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

when we went from apex 4 to apex 5, we had to access all our apex 4 apps in a developer instance (which apparently did some conversion/upgrade), and then export them and re-install them in our runtime-only apex 5 production instance. is this the case with an upgrade form apex 5.0 to 5.1.2?  or will our apex 5.0 apps just run on a 5.1.2 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the plan.

All applications should work as they did in previous versions. This is made possible via a number of features, one being compatibility mode in app settings.

See here for more detail about how APEX does a pretty good job at leaving existing apps alone.
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2016/12/phased-apex-migrations.html

This doesn't mean to say you can skip regression testing or expect everything to run smooth. It can depend on how you've built your apps.